# Android LIVE Wallpaper approach?

Tags: android, image, live-wallpaper

I'm entirely new to Android development, and I'm interested in making a live wallpaper. I was thinking about looping a set of pictures instead of drawing the animation. Is this a possible approach? If possible is this a suitable or ideal way of doing it, does it eat up memory and would i need images with different resolutions because of the fragmentation?(hundreds of different devices)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it should be fairly simple.

The main part of the Wallpaper engine is the Drawing of course. You need to handle the drawing manually, there is no easy way to loop through images... you need to code it. You will have to continuously monitor the time which has passed and adjust the displayed image based on that. You are given a Canvas object to draw to and it is all done during run-time in code.

The Wallpaper engine class has a event called onSurfaceChanged which gives you the width and height of the Surface which you will be drawing to. It will be called everytime the screen dimensions change (like if the phone is put into Landscape mode for instance). You need to have code that will handle any combination of width or height for all the device types out there. You will need to decide if you are going to stretch, center, tile or crop (Or a combination of those) the source images to fit any particular screen size. I would recommend scale to fit so that the image is either taller or wider than the screen and center the image either vertically or horizontally (cropping the extra bits) once that is done. I personally just use one source size and resize it to fit. You can opt to use several source files if you want which is the recommended approach I believe, but it's a little confusing.

I would start by creating a Live Wallpaper which just draws something basic like a shape to the screen. Then work out how to display an custom image and take it from there.

Good luck

Comment: Ohh okay so basically i can loop a set of pictures, but there is no quick and easy method?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to be *very* careful about memory if taking a frame approach to animation--probably will *not* be possible to animate full frames--much more practical to move sprites on a background.  See, fr'instance: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/

Answer (score 0):

what if you have a png frame animation that is set at a certain x and y position that sits in a spot on the background image, both would have to be rescaled